# Printing long receipt

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to print a receipt in my windowsforms application. I have written some test code to run and print lines from 0 to 100. My problem is that it is printing until line 45, and it is not giving any error. I have a thermal printer xPrinter xp-80c, on this printer the max length of the paper is 30cm. And when printing to pdf it is only printing on 1 page.
Can anyone please help here and tell what is wrong. 
Thank you in advance.

```
public static void printNewMethodFromVideoDeleteMeWhenDone()
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDialog.Document = printDocument;
        printDocument.PrintPage += printDocument3_PrintPage;
        DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
        if(result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
private static void printDocument3_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12);
            float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            int startX = 10;
            int startY = 10;
            int offset = 40;

            graphic.DrawString("Welcome to the shop", new Font("Courier New", 16), brush, startX, startY);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string productDescription = "Some text " + i.ToString().PadRight(30);
                string productTotal = string.Format("{0:c}", i.ToString());
                string line = productDescription + productTotal;

                graphic.DrawString(line, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
                offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;
            }
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Total To Pay".PadRight(30) + string.Format("{0:c}", 100.ToString()), font, brush, startX, startY + offset);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // some code here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may need to set the PaperSize [From doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.papersize.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: enable all `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` and rerun your code. You can enable this option in the `Exception Settings`. (Shortkey to the settings: `Crtl+Alt+E`)

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer I did as you suggested. I am not getting any errors. It is printing only one page.

Comment: can you debug your code and have a look at which index the for loop quits?

Comment: The loop runs fine and doesn’t stop

Answer (score 0):

use your C# programming in loop to build a HTML document and use the webBrowser.Print() function to print. This is much more easier.

Call webBrowser.ShowPrintPreview() to adjust the paper and margin to zero.

create a documentReady event for printing the document after the webBrowser finished rendering the document.

```
webBrowser.DocumentReady += webBrowser_documentReady;
```

Here is the sample project that demonstrate the idea: http://www.mediafire.com/file/te2lm9sbfvln7bp/WebBrowserPrinter.zip/file

Comment: It is a windowsforms application. I don't want to use the html document.

Comment: @PlazzaSele Yes, I understood that you are doing a winforms app. You can hide the webbrowser somewhere else, or under some other control. Then the user will not able to see the webbrowser control. Only use the webbrowser to print document, not displaying any user interface. I have used webbrowser to print document a lot in my winforms.

Comment: @PlazzaSele Here is the sample project that demonstrate the idea: http://www.mediafire.com/file/te2lm9sbfvln7bp/WebBrowserPrinter.zip/file